# Какую ошибку вывести в Spring-проекте?

Tags: java, исключения, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Пишу свой первый боевой `Spring-MVC` проект. В классе заказчика имеется кошелек(поле `double wallet`). У заказчика имеется возможность выводить деньги со счета. Хочется в методе выкинуть ошибку, если пользователь попытается снять больше денег, чем имеется на счету. Как именно это сделать?

Класс CustomerService:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.service;

import com.tinychiefdelights.model.Customer;
import com.tinychiefdelights.repository.CustomerRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CustomerService extends UserService {


    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;


    @Autowired
    public void setCustomerRepository(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }



    // Методы
    //

    public void withdrawMoney(Customer customer, double money){ // Вывести деньги со счета
        if (money <= customer.getWallet()) { // Делаем проверку, чтобы сумма указанная заказчиком была меньше кошелька
            customer.setWallet(customer.getWallet() - money);
        } else {
            //////////ЧТО МНЕ СДЕЛАТЬ ТУТ!!!!
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `throw new RuntimeException("шеф усё пропало");`

Comment: а как все это будет выглядеть с try catch можно хотя бы пример?

Comment: `try { /* делаем полезную работу */ } catch (RuntimeException ex) { /* Пишем в лог. Выводим окошко пользователю с ошибкой */ }`

Comment: при этом конструкция с if else убирается?

Comment: @ArturVartanyan В своем withdrawMoney пишешь, что если (customer.getWallet() < money) throw new InsufficientFundsException(). Название эксепшена я сам придумал. Для этой ситуации ты можешь создать свой эксепшен и унаследовать его от RuntimeException.